# Where is this inline CSS code

Tags: filters, css, admin-bar

Where is this CSS code?

I mean the `margin-top: 46px !important!;`
I need to change it to `1px` to rid of top margin. But i didn't found it in any theme's files.

**Note: I have searched the texts in all files using [FileSeek Pro](https://www.fileseek.ca/Download/)**. But didn't found anything. (even with Inspect Element in the Firefox)

[image]

Comment: Could you load the page with the Javascript being deactivated in your browser? This inline style may have been added through Javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CSS code you're seeing is added by core of WP when admin bar is showing.

The function that outputs it is called [`_admin_bar_bump_cb()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_admin_bar_bump_cb/) and it's called as hook on `wp_head`.

So how to get rid of it? Just remove this action from that hook:

```
function remove_admin_bar_bump() {
   remove_action( 'wp_head', '_admin_bar_bump_cb' );
}
add_action('get_header', 'remove_admin_bar_bump');
```

Then you can add it in your CSS and use `body.admin-bar` as context if you want to add some styles only if the admin bar is visible.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what you can do about this:

- There may be a plugin which is loading this CSS so try disabling all the plugins?
- Please check the "Addional CSS" in the customizer and check if the code is there, or check if there is any Custom CSS plugin installed
  and this is inserted in it. Also check the style.css file in your
  theme.
- Add additional CSS yourself by adding a code like this and overriding this? Here's the code:
  `html {margin-top: 1px !important;}`

If any of these doesn't fix the issue, please let me know which theme are you using.

Comment: Well, this code isn't added by any plugin... It's added by WordPress core.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't see it in view source code ( ctrl + u ), probably javascript added it.

And also, is this only available when you're logged in? I think it caused by the WordPress admin bar.

Regards,
Renz